# How can make cron job which happen at different hours and minutes

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I want to make crontab where script occurs at different minutes for each hour like this

`35 1,8,12,15,31 16,18,21 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 python backup.py`

I want script to run at `16hour and 31 minutes` but it is giving me error bad hour

i want the cron occur at

`1:35am` , then `16:31`, then `21:45`

Comment: Please indicate the exact times you want it to be running. Do it in plain expression, without the crontab expression so it is more clear.

Comment: You can use online cron task generators like this (http://www.generateit.net/cron-job/) if you unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As there is not a pattern that can match the three times, it is not possible to schedule that just with one crontab expression. You will have to use three:

```
45 21 * * * python backup.py
31 16 * * * python backup.py
35 1 * * * python backup.py
```

Note also that `python backup.py` will probably not work. You have to define full path for both files and binaries:

```
35 1 * * * /usr/bin/python /your/dir/backup.py
```

Where `/usr/bin/python` or similar can be obtained with `which python`.

Comment: i can't believe that we can't do that. so it means we can specify only one same minute interval for every hour not different minutes for different hours

Comment: If we used `35,31,45 1,16,21 * * *` it will work in all combinations of times: `1:31`, `1:35`, `1:45`, `16:31`... which I guess is not what you need.

Comment: ya, i dont want that. i will stick with one time only. how can i mention which user the cron should run

Comment: sudo to that user and from there `crontab -e`. Or also, write it like `* * * * * <user> <command>`.

Answer (score 0):

If the system which you are on has systemd, You can look into systemd timers(https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html). Then you might be able to achieve the randomness using the RandomizedDelaySec setting and an OnCalendar setting which will schedule the service to run every hour or interval you set plus will generate a RandomizedDelaySec at every run so that the interval is random.